# Number of points in a plane.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, plane-geometry

I want to prove that number of points in a plane is equal to the number of points on $ [0, 1]$.

I think of assuming a function $ f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} $ such for every $x$, $f (x)=(x, 0) $.  Is this right? May I say that $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} $  have the same number of points so $ \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} $  has the same number of points as $[0, 1] $ does?

Comment: It's important to use correct English : "I wanna" $\rightarrow$ "I want to." Besides it has just been corrected by $Matthew Leingang

Comment: Your function is only an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ so you've only proven $|\mathbb{R}|\leq |\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|$. Take a look at, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291677/equivalency-of-real-numbers-and-points-in-the-plane?rq=1